# How to correctly put the texture on?

Tags: modeling, texturing

I'm trying to put this Texture on the chest like in the reference but it doesn't look right. Any idea on how to put it on correctly ?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this (image below) is what you want, you need to unwrap again, and use this kind of setup: copy paste the *Principled BSDF* of *Material.009* to get the correct blue, mix it with your image, with the *Alpha* of the image as Factor of the *Mix Shader*:

[image]

But actually you don't need 2 materials, you could have included the image in the *Material.009* material, just make sure that the UV islands of the blue parts are overlaying the transparent parts of the image:

[image]